# javadoc doclet that embeds syntax highlighted source code

Tags: javadoc

Is there a doclet that embeds syntax highlighted source code into javadoc output?

the -linksource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#linksource option includes plain text source, but I'd like to have syntax highlighted source e.g. like the one generated by Opengrok: https://java.net/projects/opengrok/sources/opengrok-git/content/src/org/opensolaris/opengrok/Info.java

Answer (score 0):

Doclava (https://code.google.com/p/doclava/) pretty-prints source code in <pre> blocks.